# Multiple Login Feature

Tags: multiple-login

I am implementing a multiple login system, using Facebook, Twitter, Email.

If the user login with Facebook, he is able to merge his account with Twitter account or Email account, so next time login, he can press on "Login with Twitter" or key in email+password to login.

Now the problem is the merging.

If user created account A using Facebook login, modify some data, then create account B using Twitter login, and modify some data, this would be hard to merge, because both accounts will have different data.

What do app/site who use multiple login handle this kind of situation? Or is it me who makes it complicated?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main point is not storing any detailed account information with the login method. This is probably what your user account DB looks like now:

```
- account_id: …
  facebook_auth_info: …
  username: …
  birth_date: …
- account_id: …
  twitter_auth_info: …
  username: …
  birth_date: …
```

Now this schema should make it a no-op to “merge accounts”:

```
- account_id: …
  facebook_auth_info: …
  twitter_auth_info: …
  username: …
  birth_date: …
```

In other words, treat Facebook, Twitter and other as a “identity providers” and allow for multiple identity providers per your own account.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is to keep separated third party login details and use tables like email and third party login details interchangeable to authenticate a user. This way you can have a customer that get authorized either by using email or using a third party login. This does not mean that the same user can login either with email&password or third party provider. This I find it helpful to avoid having all the time fields for third party providers in the User table and if you want to add more login providers you don't have to alter any table, just add another entry in Types table.

For example I would use a **Users** table where you you keep all details for a customer but login details. No email, password or any other login details. These details are held in separate tables and are linked by the PK from this table. **This table will map 1:1 to the Emails table**. For example a schema might be:

```
- Id (PK)
- FirstName
- SecondName
- etc.
```

Then I'll have an **Emails** table where I would keep the email and password for a user. You can also have extra details like Id and Verified (to know if email is verified). Please be aware of keeping plain text passwords or keeping pairs email - password in your db. This is an important security concern and I would not discuss it here. I would also use a UserId column to map emails to users. **This will map 1:1 to Users table**. A schema might be:

```
- Id (PK)
- Email
- Password
- UserId (FK)
- Verified
```

To handle the third party login details I'll use a table called **ThirdPartyUsers**. In this table I will store a UserId to map one record from this table to one record from User tables. Basically this table can replace Email table and you can move away from holding email - password in your db. In this table I would keep a ProviderCode that is a code from types table and a ProviderId that is an Id provided by third party logins. This Ids are unique per third party providers and don't change per user. You can pair a ProviderCode with a ProviderId to make a composite key. **This will map 1:1 to Users table**. A schema might be:

```
- Id (PK)
- UserId (FK)
- ProviderCode 
- ProviderId
```

To have a unified User account I would have a **MasterUsers** table where you define a User as a Master user and you define into a link table its children. Through its children I understand any account that has the same email address. This means a classic account and any third party login providers. Using this you can a unique Master and multiple children. **This would map 1:1 to Users table and 1:* to MasterLinkToChildren table**.  A schema might be :

```
- Id (PK)
- UserId
```

To link multiple customers to one MasterUser I would use a link table called **MasterLinkToChildren** (or any naming you prefer). In this I would have two columns for storing UserIds for childrens and MasterId for their parent. An important thing I would do is to make any MasterUser also be a children of himself in the Link table so when you update the MasterUser you would keep consistency between your records. **This will map *:1 to MasterUsers and 1:1 to Users table**. A schema might be:

```
- MasterId (FK)
- UserId (FK)
```

Finally I would have a **Codes** table where I would store unique code for each third party login provider. **This would map 1:* to ThirdPartyUsers**. A schema like:

```
- Id (PK)
- Code (Unique)
```

It might look like a lot of code and many tables but in this way you can preserve unique user login or you can unify everything under one Master account. I wouldn't merge them automatically but I will offer the user the option to do that. Another thing you need to consider is not to allow users to login or merge accounts before they verified their account. I didn't use a Verified column on ThirdPartyUsers table as I don't want to verify this type of users but you can do this as well.

By using a Codes table you can extend your third party login providers without altering other tables.